# Flutter Freezed + Bloc- How to emit same state twice and make UI Rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, freezed

I have a question regarding Freezed+Bloc package

Does anyone know how to **emit the same state twice** but making Bloc knows he has to **rebuild UI**?

I'm not being able to

**I know I would be able to achieve this using Equatable, but I don't quite understand how to implement it while using Freezed*

Comment: Could you add an example of your cubit and state for more context on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes sure, sorry, let me elaborate:
I have a **Settings cubit**
Wich basically has Settings-**Current** or **updating** state, both hold a **Settings**

This saves user pref as language, etc... But it also holds some kind of fav pages

- In Settings Screen I emit SettingsUpdating to notify the user of UI Changes (Language changes in real time 4 exmpl)

- If user saves changes, settingsCurrent is emited  with updated ones, if not, it has previous ones

Comment: -So in a home screen user can add fav pages, but I use settingsCurrent to build UI since we are not in settings screen, and i have to emit first settings updating then settings current to notify of UI changes to the bloc

Sorry comment was too long

Comment: Could you add the code, so it would be easier to understand? Here is [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If this is still relevant to anyone, here is the solution to the problem.

```
@Freezed(equal: false)
class YourState with _$YourState {
  ...your state factories...
}
```

You need to specify equal: false in the annotation.
The problem is that Freezed extends Equitable, but the Bloc does not change states if they are identical.